# How to fix an error, when adding a controller to my FXML

Tags: javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX project for university, where we have to program the game "Set". I wanted to test my code and add some example cards which I already have designed but as soon as I add my controller to my FXML file it always crashes, without the controller it works fine but i just see a blank window.

This is my FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root fx:id="omg" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="980.0" prefWidth="1400.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.gui.testing">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="card12" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="1130.0" layoutY="690.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card11" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="870.0" layoutY="690.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card10" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="690.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card9" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="690.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card8" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="1130.0" layoutY="370.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card7" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="870.0" layoutY="370.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card6" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="370.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card5" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="370.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card4" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="1130.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card3" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="870.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card2" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="card1" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <ImageView fx:id="background" fitHeight="980.0" fitWidth="1400.0" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

This is my controller:

```
package test.gui;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class testing{

    @FXML
    ImageView card1;

    @FXML
    ImageView card2;

    @FXML
    ImageView card3;

    @FXML
    ImageView card4;

    @FXML
    ImageView card5;

    @FXML
    ImageView card6;

    @FXML
    ImageView card7;

    @FXML
    ImageView card8;

    @FXML
    ImageView card9;

    @FXML
    ImageView card10;

    @FXML
    ImageView card11;

    @FXML
    ImageView card12;

    @FXML
    ImageView background;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane omg;


    public void addPictures() throws IOException {
            card1.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/1.jpg")), null));
            card2.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/2.jpg")), null));
            card3.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/3.jpg")), null));
            card4.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/4.jpg")), null));
            card5.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/5.jpg")), null));
            card6.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/6.jpg")), null));
            card7.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/7.jpg")), null));
            card8.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/8.jpg")), null));
            card9.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/9.jpg")), null));
            card10.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/10.jpg")), null));
            card11.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/11.jpg")), null));
            card12.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/cards/12.jpg")), null));
            background.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/background/background.jpg")), null));


    }
}
```

And my main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/testing.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Set The Game!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);


    }
```

And this are the errors I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at SetGame/test.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application test.Main
```

Comment: The resource path looks correct. All that is left to check would be to verify that the fxml is included in the classpath at subdirectory (or entry of the jar) `gui/testing.fxml`. Unfortunately no info that would narrow down the required path or show the classpath is available here making it impossible to help you without making major guesses...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/gui/testing.fxml"));
```

instead of

```
  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/testing.fxml"));
```

else try to remove 1st "/" from /gui/test.......

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it still gives me the same error, I think I will start the project again and do testing everytime I change something to figure out the errors then. But I dont know, why it never finds the class path....

Comment: I will do some more test when i've got time.. stay tuned!!